# Decompress LZO indexed files

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, lzo, snowplow

I need to decompress some `lzo indexed` files.
First, I've tried to decompress the first lzo file with `lzop` but in the first line of the fie i have some extra byte.

How I can decompress the file correctly?

Comment: I'm also facing this problem, but I cannot find any solution for this.
I have several lzo files, e.g., 1.lzo, 1.lzo.index, 2.lzo, 2.lzo.index, but I have no idea how to extract them...